# FOR loop in Oracle SQL or Apply SQL to multiple Oracle tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

My SQL is a bit rusty, so I don't know whether the following is even possible:

I have multiple tables `t_a`, `t_b`, `t_c` with the same column layout and I want to apply the same operation to them, namely output some aggregation into another table. For a table `t_x` this would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t_x_aggregate (
    <here the col definitions which are the same for all new tables t_[abc]_aggregate>
);

INSERT INTO t_x_aggregate(id, ...)
SELECT id, SUM(factor*amount)
FROM t_x
WHERE some fixed condition
GROUP BY id;
```

I now want to execute something like a FOR loop around this:

```
for t_x in t_a, t_b, t_c
    CREATE TABLE ...
    INSERT INTO ...
end for
```

Is this possible in SQL? Or would I need to build a wrapper in another language for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the FOR loop you need to use PL/SQL like this:(*)

```
declare
  type array_t is table of varchar2(10);
  array array_t := array_t('a', 'b', 'c'); 
  lo_stmt varchar2(2000);
begin
  lo_stmt :=
  'CREATE TABLE t_'||array(i)||'_aggregate ('||
  '    <here the col definitions which are the same for all new tables t_[abc]_aggregate>'||
  ');'||
  ''||
  'INSERT INTO t_'||array(i)||'_aggregate(id, ...)'||
  'SELECT id, SUM(factor*amount)'||
  'FROM t_'||array(i)||
  'WHERE some fixed condition'||
  'GROUP BY id;'||   
  execute immediate lo_stmt;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Look also at this SO question: [How to use Oracle PL/SQL to create...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64437662/how-to-use-oracle-pl-sql-to-create-ten-similar-tables-from-a-given-oracle-source)

(*) @Littlefoot describes in the 2nd part of his answer valuable background to this program.

Answer (score 1):

So, the result of that operation would be 3 new tables? `T_A_AGGREGATE`, `T_B_AGGREGATE` and `T_C_AGGREGATE`?

I think that the fastest way is to write 3 separate `CREATE TABLE` statements, e.g.

```
create table t_a_aggregate as
  select id, sum(factor * amount) suma
  from t_a
  where some_condition
  group by id;

create table t_b_aggregate as
  select id, sum(factor * amount) suma
  from t_b
  where some_condition
  group by id;

create table t_c_aggregate as
  select id, sum(factor * amount) suma
  from t_c
  where some_condition
  group by id;
```

OK; I understand that queries aren't that simple, but nothing much changes - only table names in `CREATE` and `FROM` (perhaps somewhere else, but that's more or less "it"). Any decent text editor's *search/replace* capabilities should be able to do it quickly.

If you want to do it *dynamically* in a loop (read: PL/SQL), you can - but dynamic SQL doesn't scale, is difficult to maintain, is painful to debug. Therefore, if you're doing it *only once*, consider running 3 separate statements.

---

How to do it dynamically?

You'd have to create a string (we usually put them into a locally declared variable) which contains the whole DDL statement. Why? Because you can't execute DDL from a PL/SQL otherwise.

If there are multiple tables and/or columns involved, you'll have to combine "fixed" parts of the statement (like `create table`, `select`, `from`, `order by`) concatenated with "dynamic" parts - such as column names. Note that in between you have to concatenate commas as separators. Pay attention to usage of multiple single quotes as you have to *escape* them (or use the q-quoting mechanism).

Also, for multiple columns you'll probably have to do it in a loop, concatenating each new column to previously composed string.

It (the statement stored into the varirable) is the executed by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. If it is correctly written, it'll succeed. Otherwise, it'll fail, but it won't tell you *why* it failed (that's why I said difficult debugging").

So, instead of executing it, we usually *display* that string (using `dbms_output.put_line`) so that we see how it looks like and - using copy/paste - try to execute it.

Basically, it can be quite complex and - as I said - difficult to maintain and debug.

Comment: I appreciate you practical thinking, @Littlefoot, but that's not really the point. What would it look like with PL/SQL?

Comment: I added some more info (begins at "How to do it dynamically?". Have a look, please.