# How to use Oracle PL/SQL to create ten similar tables from a given Oracle source table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle18c

I have data in one table in a oracle database and I want to “split” this table in SQLplus into ten tables based on the content of one column.

Source table is `all_data` with columns:

`kind`, `time_period`, `amount`

`kind` is the row to split on: the value of  `kind` In each row is exactly one of ten different names "peter", "maria", "eric", etc...

Now I want to create ten tables, one for each name. The first table for name "peter" would be created manually in SQL as:

```
CREATE TABLE peter_data  AS (
  SELECT p.kind, p.time_period, p.amount as amount_peter
    FROM all_data
    WHERE kind = 'peter'
)
;
```

**How can I use PL/SQL to create all ten tables `peter_data`, `maria_data`, `eric_data`, etc.?**

---

I tried:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE array_t IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(10);
    ARRAY array_t := array_t('peter', 'maria', 'eric');   
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
        CREATE TABLE ARRAY(i) AS (
          SELECT p.kind, p.time_period, p.amount as amount_peter
            FROM all_data
            WHERE kind = ARRAY(i)
        )
        ;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

but this gives understandably the error “*PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"...*”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your DDL statement in a string and call `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE array_t IS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(10);
  ARRAY array_t := array_t('peter', 'maria', 'eric');   
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'CREATE TABLE ' || ARRAY(i) || ' ( kind, time_period, amount_' || ARRAY(i) || ' ) AS'
      || ' SELECT kind, time_period, amount'
      || ' FROM all_data WHERE kind = ''' || ARRAY(i) || '''';
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*(and remove `p.` as you didn't define the alias `p` anywhere.)*

Then, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE all_data ( kind, time_period, amount ) AS
SELECT 'peter', DATE '2020-01-01', 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'maria', DATE '2020-02-01', 42 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'eric',  DATE '2020-03-01', 11 FROM DUAL;
```

Then you get the tables:

```sql
SELECT * FROM peter;
```

> ```
> KIND  | TIME_PERIOD         | AMOUNT_PETER
> :---- | :------------------ | -----------:
> peter | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |           23
> ```

```sql
SELECT * FROM maria;
```

> ```
> KIND  | TIME_PERIOD         | AMOUNT_MARIA
> :---- | :------------------ | -----------:
> maria | 2020-02-01 00:00:00 |           42
> ```

```sql
SELECT * FROM eric;
```

> ```
> KIND | TIME_PERIOD         | AMOUNT_ERIC
> :--- | :------------------ | ----------:
> eric | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 |          11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7d652f028acc688654a83dfbb51ff36)*

Answer (score 2):

You need `dynamic SQL` for it and with Oracle we can use `execute immediate` to do so.

```
declare
  type array_t is table of varchar2(10);
  array array_t := array_t();
  lo_stmt varchar2(2000);
begin
  select distinct kind
    bulk collect into array
    from all_data;
  
  for i in 1..array.count loop
    --dbms_output.put_line(array(i));
    lo_stmt :=
    'create table '||array(i)||'_data '||
    'as '||
    'select kind,time_period,amount '||
    '  from all_data '||
    ' where kind = '''||array(i)||'''';
    --dbms_output.put_line(lo_stmt);
    execute immediate lo_stmt;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Demo can be seen [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=84c42b05e0128aafb3515c26c139d53d)

**OR with a single statement**

```
declare
  type array_t is table of varchar2(4000);
  array array_t := array_t();
  lo_stmt varchar2(2000);
begin
  select distinct 'create table '||kind||'_data '||
    'as '||
    'select kind,time_period,amount '||
    'from all_data '||
    'where kind = '''||kind||''''
    bulk collect into array
    from all_data;
  
  for i in 1..array.count loop
    --dbms_output.put_line(array(i));
    execute immediate array(i);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Also works [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4ee181d47f556b2624ec29bff1e58a0)

Comment: Thanks for the dbfiddles. - Very helpful!